# Calling a compiled C library function from Qt C++ produces unexpected behaviour

Tags: c++, c, qt, debugging, linker

I am on Windows, and I have 2 projects: One is made in C, which I have compiled into a DLL library, and a Qt C++ project, which I am linking with the C library.

When I've tried linking the C library in the past with C code, it works fine. But there seems to be a problem when I try to link it with C++ code (on both Qt here and on Linux in general), even if I insert the `extern "C"` block where I include the C header files.

The strangest part is when debugging, the code does things that just... shouldn't happen?

Here is the C code that I am calling:

```c
// Defined in a header file elsewhere...
typedef struct _nodeTrueProperties {
    bool isDefined;
    bool needFuncName;
    bool _mallocd;

    const DType *inputTypes;
    long numInputs;

    const DType *outputTypes;
    long numOutputs;
} NodeTrueProperties;

// The actual code...
NodeTrueProperties d_semantic_get_node_properties(struct _sheet *sheet,
                                                  const char *name,
                                                  size_t lineNum,
                                                  const char *funcName,
                                                  NameDefinition *definition) {
    VERBOSE(5, "Getting node properties of node %s on line %zu in %s...\n",
            name, lineNum, sheet->filePath)

    NodeTrueProperties out =
        (NodeTrueProperties){false, false, true, NULL, 0, NULL, 0};

    // Most cases use this to build up the output types.
    DType *outputTypes = NULL;

    // First, let's check if it's a special function like Start.
    // We do this now so we don't need to search all of our includes
    // for this function.
    if (strcmp(name, "Start") == 0) {

        // THIS IS THE SECTION THAT SHOULD AND DOES RUN!

        out.isDefined  = true;
        out.numOutputs = 1;

        outputTypes    = (DType *)d_malloc(sizeof(DType));
        outputTypes[0] = TYPE_EXECUTION;

        out.outputTypes = (const DType *)outputTypes;
    } else if (strcmp(name, "Return") == 0) {
        // ... stuff that shouldn't run...
    } // ...

    return out;
}
```

And this is the Qt C++ code calling that function:

```cpp
#include "nodegraphicsitem.h"

#include <QPainter>

extern "C" {
    #include <dsemantic.h>
}

// ...

void NodeGraphicsItem::setupNode(Sheet *sheet, QString name, QPointF position) {
    _name = name;
    _position = position;
    _sheet = sheet;
    _size = STARTING_SIZE;

    // Set the QGraphicsItem flags.
    setFlags(ItemIsMovable | ItemIsSelectable);

    // Get the true properties of the node.
    NameDefinition nodeDefinition;
    QByteArray nameByteArray      = name.toLatin1();
    const char *nameCharArray     = nameByteArray.constData();

    // THIS IS THE CALL TO THE COMPILED C FUNCTION
    NodeTrueProperties properties =
        d_semantic_get_node_properties(sheet, nameCharArray, 1, NULL,
                                       &nodeDefinition);

    // THIS FUNCTION DOES SOME WHACKY STUFF
    d_semantic_free_true_properties(properties);

    // ...
}
```

Everything compiles fine, but it does not run fine at all:

What I expect my `NodeTrueProperties` to look like, based on the if statement that runs (since the name passed in is `"Start"`), should look like this: `{true, false, true, NULL, 0, (pointer to DType array), 1}`. What I actually get is `{true, false, false, NULL, 1, NULL, 0}` according to the debugger:

[image: What the debugger says the values are]

Another really whacky artifact is an if statement activates in the C code, even though the condition, according to the debugger, is false (`trueProperties._mallocd == false`):

[image: If statement activates for some reason]

I use CMake and VS2017 in Win32 mode to compile the C project into a DLL, and I use Qt Creator with the MSVC2017 32bit kit to compile the Qt C++ project.

Comment: My guess is, the two compilers don't agree on the binary layout of `NodeTrueProperties`. Try printing `sizeof(NodeTrueProperties)` on both C and C++ sides. `bool` is a built-in type in C++, but some macro in C, possibly expanding to a type of different size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit thanks to Igor Tandetnik's comment: My `bool` that I created in the C library (4 bytes = `int`) was a different size to the `bool` type in the C++ program (1 byte), which I assume ended up changing the `NodeTrueProperties` struct between the program and the library as well.

For reference, I changed my `bool` definition in C from this:

```c
/**
 * \enum bool
 * \brief A boolean.
 */
typedef enum {
    false, ///< `false`
    true   ///< `true`
} bool;
```

to including the `stdbool.h` header file:

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this format: `@ #include <dsemantic.h> @`
I hope this helps solve your problem.